# Run Python script at start-up from php when python script is stored on a raspberrypi not in the same computer I have my php script on?

Tags: python, php, raspberry-pi

I am using a barcode reader connected to a raspberrypi with python script to read barcodes and send them to be processed in php through including the ip of file.php in python.

my python script is on a different physical machine than the PHP script.

I want to start-up the python script from the php code to enable users to scan barcodes automatically.

**I am new to python and have not used it before.

Comment: You'd have to have a webservice running on the Pi so the PHP code could send a request to the Pi to trigger the startup of the python script. But maybe it would be better to have something on the Pi which simply starts that script automatically when the machine is first started.

Comment: thank you so much... actually when i thought about it... that's what i ended up doing. now i run it using schedule from the python code its self which is more logical for my case. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must run your Python as daemon and contact Python via PHP using a socket or a REST call